# MySQL Normalized Database Design

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I have the following `table structure`. The requirements are that it needs to be normalized to `3rd normal`.

I am not sure about the `subscriberAddress` is that needs to be in a new table or it can just go under `subscribers`? What do you think? Is the rest fine?

```
users(userName, userFirstName, userLastName, password, image)
userRole(userRole)
subscribers(email, firstName, lastName)
subscriberAddress(geoLocationLatitude, geoLocationLongtitude)
products(productName,productPrice, productQuantity, productImage)
```

Comment: Is it your college assignment?

Comment: This question is highly depending on what you are doing and there are various arguments for both sides. Try to ask clear and well defined questions. WHAT are you planning? MAYBE we can give you advice then

Comment: it´s for a webshop, where you can subscribe and subscribers will be displayed on a page with their info + on a map (all on the same page)

Comment: Hi. Read your textbook. Normalization to 3NF involves FDs (functional dependencies). What are yours? We can only guess, and common sense isn't typically enough because they are application-specific. Anyway you should be showing your attempts--read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework' and [ask]. Constraints between tables are irrelevant. The two answers so far are worthless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see any reference between tables. How subscribers and subscriberAddress are related?
If a subscriber has only one address, you can put it into subscribers.
If a subscriber can present many addresses, put them into another table with a reference to that subscriber .

Comment: they have only one address.

Answer (score 0):

Do the tables conform to 1NF and 2NF first of all? They need to before they can be in 3NF.

Can the table structure be amended? If so I would add a unique identifier e.g. subscriberID, this is the primary key for the subscriber table. This ID can be added to the subscriberAddress, acting as a foreign key.

I'd keep the subscriberAddress table separate.